# Codeigniter is it bad to use User Agent class to output different views for mobiles

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to tackle an application where the designs would differ on mobile as it would to desktop.

Is it bad practice, in Codeigniter to use the User Agent class and load a view dependent on what device you are on but parse the same data to the view.

Example:

```
if ($this->agent->is_mobile() && $this->input->get('signin') != 'true') {
  $this->data['meta_title'] = $this->data['meta_title'].' | Splash Page';

  $this->load->view('path/to/view/mobile/splash', $this->data);
} else {
  $this->data['meta_title'] = $this->data['meta_title'].' | Login';

  $this->load->view('path/to/view/login', $this->data);
}
```

An example of this usage may not only be the difference in design but maybe if you wanted to divert to a splash page or something too.

Is it bad practice to build applications in Codeigniter in this way?

Answer (score 0):

That's a somewhat loaded question ...

If building this particular functionality with CodeIgniter is a pre-condition, then that's the best you can do.

However, with PHP being a server-side language, it cannot probe the client's browser directly and has to rely on self-reported data, which is what CI's User agent library does.
That shouldn't be bad by itself, because (for example) it allows a desktop users to report themselves as mobile clients and that may be useful to them, but on the other hand isn't reliable.

Instead, you should use a client-side technology such as JavaScript to probe the visitor's browser in order to detect its capabilities. And at that point, it doesn't matter if you're using CodeIgniter for the back-end or not, because it's not the PHP framework that's responsible for this particular task.

Comment: So in something like a CMS (content management system) when working with the backend, their would be nothing wrong with what I proposed?

Comment: That depends ... there's no straightforward answer.

Comment: Or should I just have 2 versions of the HTML in one page and hide/show based on the device?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use media queries to change the website's design for different devices and viewports (it's possible you know)

eg. showing an element on desktop and removing on mobile can be as simple as adding a `display: none` to the targeted element.

```
@media (min-width:500px){/*Class name*/{/*properties*/}}
@media (max-width:499px){/*Class name*/{/*properties*/}}
```

> This just says that any time there is a screen size bigger than 500px, certain styles will be applied, and when it is below that, it will apply different properties.

That said, it's isn't really a bad practice but, it isn't very ideal either.